# Trouble with media query

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I'm trying out frontend mentor projects and I'm having trouble serving a picture of different viewport size(for desktop) and I don't know what's wrong, I used the picture element and declared at what width the picture should be served but it doesn't work.
The confusing aspect is that flexbox and grid display properties don't have much effect. The small mobile image doesn't get replaced with the desktop one.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

\*::before,
\*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
}

main.background {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
  article.card-body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 346px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    section.card-details {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 25px;
      picture.image-container {
        width: 346px;
        height: 243px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      header.title {
        color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 13px;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        transform: scale(0.9);
      }
      h1.title-detail {
        color: hsl(212, 21%, 14%);
        font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 17px;
      }
    }
  }
}

p.section-detail {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

h2.price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', sans-serif;
  color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2.price::after {
  content: '$169.99';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: center;
  color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 23px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

img.perfume-image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 346px;
  height: 243px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

img.cart-icon {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

button.add-to-cart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  color: #fff;
  width: 298px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button.add-to-cart:hover {
  background-color: hsl(158, 36%, 13%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.btn-text {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

footer.challenge-userinfo {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  div.attribution {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  div.attribution a {
    color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  article.card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-width: 616px;
  }
  picture-image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .card-details {
    width: 308px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="background">
  <img src="./images/image-product-mobile.jpg" alt="perfume"> PERFUME
  <h1>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
  <p>A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
  <h2>$149.99</h2>
  <img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart">Add to Cart Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="https://github.com/David4bay">David Bayode</a>.
```

I tried using messing with the min and max-widths to see if it's the width misbehaving.

Comment: I tried to format a bit and put the code in a fiddle but your HTML is malformed. FWIW I do see the sass TAG and obviously the snippet will NOT run here but I used that more for formatting and to show the malformed HTML

Comment: FWIW that is a huge code wall of CSS do do what should be something fairly simple

Comment: On Stack Overflow we ask that you only upload the code reproducing your problem, not all of your code

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't sure what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, my nested scss styles had a high specificity that prevented media queries from being triggered.